# How to drop one level of a multiindex in pandas

Tags: pandas

Im trying to drop a level of my multi index using [drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html), but I cant get it to work.

```
iterables = [["bar", "baz"], ["bar", "baz"]]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables, names=["first", "second"])
df = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4], index=index) 
df
```

df looks like this:

```
first  second
bar    one       1
       two       2
baz    one       3
       two       4
```

I want to drop the `second` level of the multi index, so that I would have as result:

```
first
bar    1
bar    2
baz    3
baz    4
```

However, `df.drop(index=['second'])` and `df.drop(index=['second'],level=1)` dont work, so Im a little confused on how to get it done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you use [pd.MultiIndex.droplevel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.droplevel.html#pandas.MultiIndex.droplevel)

```
df=df.droplevel(level=1)

or

df=df.droplevel('second')

df
```

```
first
bar    1
bar    2
baz    3
baz    4
dtype: int64
```

Comment: or droplevel('second'). Thanks, that method does the trick!